# Unity3D Arange multiple gameobjects on top of cube without falling

Tags: unity-game-engine

This is for a board game. Each tile (a cube) can have up to 6 tokens on top. What happens is based on some logic, I move a token to the top center of cube (which works fine). When another token come into the same tile surface, I want any tokens already on the surface to move away and give room to the incoming tile.

Right now, since these tokens have rigidbodies they get pushed away, but I don't have much control over how those tokens should be placed. Main problem is I need to utilize the surface area of the cube to determine exact point a tile should move. I don't want it to fall or push away from the cube bounds.

I was thinking to place 6 empty gameobjects as children in the cube that has possible areas a token can move on the surface. But then the child local coordinates and token coordinates are different.

What kind of approaches are available?

[image]

Comment: If you just need them to stay on the cube, you can make an invisible set of colliders along the outside to hold them in.   Otherwise, you could do something where you find the shortest path to an empty space and move all the blues along the path one space to make room for the new guy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach would be creating a script for the block like the one below containing.

1. An index of how many tokens are currently present on it and
2. An array of vector2 positions (consider a 3*3 matrix )
3. And a distance from center value to multiple with the positions.

So when adding a token to the cube you'll have to pass the cube tiles position (it will be the center of the cube tile so I called it cubeCenter) and the token to be added.

first check whether the index is -1, meaning there are not tokens so place the token in the center(cubeCenter) and increment the index to 0.

else 
change the position of the previous token to pos[index]*distanceFromCubeCenter +cubeCenter, increment the index and set new token's position to cubeCenter.

Consider if the cube tile is at (3,0,3) and there is already a token in the center so the index will be 0. if another token comes then the position of the old token will be will be (-1*0.3+3,0,-1*0.3+3) =(2.7,0,2.7) and will place the token like the bottom left in your image and the new token will be in the center. Similarly, if another token comes then the token in the center will go to (3,0,2.7) like the bottom center of your image.

3*3 matrix but in this case, only 5 positions are used.

```
| (-1,0,1) |(0,0,1) |(1,0,1) |
| (-1,0,0) |(0,0,0) |(1,0,0) |
| (-1,0,-1)|(0,0,-1)|(1,0,-1)|
```

the code is in 3d since I saw the blue z-axis, you will have to change it depending on how you are storing/moving the tokens.

```
     int index = -1;
    public Vector3[] pos; //(-1,0,-1),(0,0,-1),(1,,0,0),(-1,,0,1),(0,0,1)
    public float distanceFromCubeCenter = 0.3f; // spacing from the center of the cube

    public void AddToCube(Vector3 cubeCenter,GameObject token)
    {
        if (index == -1)  //only for the first token on cube
        {
            token.transform.position = cubeCenter; 
            index++; // increment index to 0
        }
        else
        {
            previousTokenOnThisCube.transform.position = pos[index] * distanceFromCubeCenter + cubeCenter;
            index++;
            token.transform.position = cubeCenter;
        }
    }
```